# How do I stop Hibernate from hitting child tables?

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

[image: DB Image]

As evident from the image, the individual Blocks Apple Block, Banana Block, Cat Block and Dog Block have a foreign key reference to Block Reference Table, which intern has a reference to Effective Date Table which goes back to Block Definition Table.

This is my code

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "Block_Reference_Table", schema = "mySchema", catalog = "myCatelog")
public class BlockReference extends AuditableEntity<Long> implements java.io.Serializable {
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Id
  @Column(name = "block_ref_table_id", nullable = false)
  private Long blockReferenceTableId;

  @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  @JoinColumn(name = "ref_to_effective_date_table")
  private EffectiveDateTable effectiveDate;

  @OneToOne(mappedBy = "BlockReference", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  private AppleBlock appleBlock;

  @OneToOne(mappedBy = "BlockReference", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  private BananaBlock bananaBlock;

  @OneToOne(mappedBy = "BlockReference", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  private CatBlock catBlock; 

  @OneToOne(mappedBy = "BlockReference", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  private DogBlock dogBlock;
```

I am trying to retrive individual Block based on Effective date.
The issue I am facing is Hibernate is hitting all the other blocks (child Tables). How do I avoid this?

What I want is, If I am trying to retrieve Apple Block based on Effective Date, engine should not hit Banana Block, Cat Block or Dog Block.
When I am trying to retrieve Banana Block based on Effective Date, engibe should not hit Apple Block, Cat Block or Dog Block.

So on and so fourth.

Answer (score 0):

Add `@JsonIgnoreProperties` to specify what values to ignore in child json

Below is sample implementation:

EntityA Class:

```
@Entity
public class EntityA {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "entityA")
    @JsonIgnoreProperties("entityA") // Ignore entityA in entityB
    private EntityB entityB;
}
```

EntityB Class:

```
@Entity
public class EntityB {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String info;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "entity_a_id")
    @JsonIgnoreProperties("entityB") // Ignore entityB in entityA
    private EntityA entityA;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By hitting I assume you are saying that you are trying to retrieve data and the query generated by JPA returns a large resultset with unwanted child entities which will affect the performance, Here is something I observed in your entity definition, you have done a very good job by making the fetch type of the OneToOne relation as lazy but note that even though you change the default fetch the parent side association will behave like FetchType.EAGER. So when you fetch the BLOCK entity the associated child entities are also loaded along with it.

Long answer short we can work around this by using  @LazyToOne(LazyToOneOption.NO_PROXY) on the parent side.

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "Block_Reference_Table", schema 
= "mySchema", catalog = "myCatelog")
public class BlockReference extends 
AuditableEntity<Long> implements 
java.io.Serializable {
@GeneratedValue(strategy = 
GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Id
@Column(name = "block_ref_table_id", nullable 
= false)
private Long blockReferenceTableId;

@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = " 
ref_to_effective_date_table")
private EffectiveDateTable effectiveDate;

@LazyToOne(LazyToOneOption.NO_PROXY)
private AppleBlock appleBlock;
```